# query with the memory representation?

Tags: c, memory, structure, output

```
int main()
{
    struct books
    {
        char name;
        float price;
    }b1;
    printf("%u   %u",&b1.name,&b1.price);
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:-

```
2686728    2686732
```

As the `sizeof(char)` is 1, so why there is a difference of 4 in the above two addresses?

Comment: Short answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: @jrd1 : Very useful article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding. The compiler inserts 3 bytes of padding between the `name` and `price` fields so accessing `price` doesn't run into alignment troubles.

Comment: @kevingomes: Unused space.

Comment: see @jrd comment above, It is big topic but you will find it useful.